# Change TeamViewer to unattended

Tags: remote-desktop, teamviewer

I am using TeamViewer's remote assistance for the first time to help someone fix their computer from across the globe. I had them download the stand-alone app and give me the credentials. I did a lot of things and everything worked fine. The problem is there's a lot more stuff that's going to require reboots and my friend won't be there. How can I set it up so I can reconnect after the reboot since I cannot guide my friend through the process of setting up the normal service, and I cannot launch the full version remotely since it already has a session running.

The computer does already have version 10 installed on the desktop.

I am assuming that just putting the stand-alone app in the startup folder will generate a whole new set of credentials if launched after a reboot, thus locking me out correct?

I would normally setup VNC for this, but the router is locked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get them to set up a permanent password for unattended access, then tell you it.
This is, of course, a huge security hole for them, so they need to trust you. It gives you total access to their machine at any time.

I call this the Grandparental Control password ;-)

It is sensible, if not hugely secure, to use the same password as the machine's main admin account logon.
If the remote machine is running Windows, they will also see the Windows logon box.

It goes without saying that I wouldn't use this simple type of setup on anything other than a family computer, & for security your remotee ought to change passwords & remove the permanent logon option afterwards.

[image]

Info distilled from [How-To Geek - Help Computer Users Remotely with TeamViewer](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27120/help-computer-users-remotely-with-teamviewer/)